# Upload an image by using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a photo by using ajax.

My input:

```
<input type="file" name="defaultPhoto">
```

A part of my jQuery code.

`var form = #insertCredentials`

```
var defaultPhoto = $('#' + form + ' ' + '[name = "defaultPhoto"]').prop('files');
```

I'm sending `defaultPhoto` through an ajax call to my php alongside with other form inputs.

The console gives back this error below:

`TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have implemented the `AJAX` way of file uploading using `Dropzone JS`. 
It will really make your life simple

Check the **[Dropzone.js Website](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)**

All you need to do is instantiate the dropzonejs object and set the `options`

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      accept: function(file, done) {
        if (file.name == "image.jpg") {
          done("Naha, you don't.");
        }
        else { done(); }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't send file via ajax
try to use hidden iframe in form target with normal submit

```
<form name="" action="/your_iframe_action_url" taget="hidden_iframe_name">

<input type="file" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe_name" style="width:0; height:0" />
```

In your_iframe_action_url you can call javascript parent functions to execute event success or failure... that simulate underground upload

Answer (score -1):

you can use `document.getElementById('whatever').files;`

to get the file
and then use

```
formdata
```

to send the files via ajax.

here is the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

you can also use File reader to show file on loaded

here is the example for [filereader](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)